# Using spy() in Julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia, spy

I am trying to use spy(). But I am not getting the use of it right. I think my error has something to do with this: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2121

I have a 300x300 Array{Float64,2}

```
using PyPlot
pygui(true)
spy(I) # where I is my 300x300 array
```

and it gives me this error:

```
LoadError: PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
TypeError("object of type 'PyCall.jlwrap' has no len()",)
  File "/home/ashley/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3154, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ashley/.julia/v0.4/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1539, in plot
    zs = np.ones(len(xs)) * zs
```

I have tried specifying `spy(I, zs=zeros(size(I))` but then I just get the error:

```
LoadError: ArgumentError: function spy does not accept keyword arguments
while loading In[260], in expression starting on line 13
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i tested your code in julia-v0.4 with no error, but spy just drew nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spy` shows the non-zero elements. Apparently it doesn't show anything if there are *no* non-zero elements.

```
M = sprand(300, 300, 0.1)  # generate a sparse matrix with density 0.1 of non-zeros
M = full(M)
spy(M)
```

works for me.

Comment: Thank you - this works for me. But only when I am using the terminal version of julia. When I try run it in a script using an editor (so far sublime and vim) it builds but nothing happens - i.e. nothing shows. I know this is a separate question so pls just say if you would prefer I start another thread - but how do I do this with an editor?

Comment: I guess this has to do with whether the editor "knows" how to interact with the graphics package. I would recommend the Jupyter Notebook for this kind of interactive graphing.

Comment: I would like to find an easy way to do Julia without notebook. But I hear you - thanks.

Comment: wasn't using interactive mode with IJulia. Putting `plt[:show]()` at the end did the trick.